# Iterating over two collections with two loops

Tags: java, collections

I have the following code :

```
for (Object a : collection1) {
    for (Object d : collection2) {
        if (a.getM().equals(d.getM())
                && a.getB().equals(d.getB())) {
            if (!a.getC().equals(d.getC())) {
                String toPrint = "This is different  :a.getC() + d.getC() !";
                System.out.println(toPrint);
                different.add(toPrint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*The problem is:* Instead of printing just the element which is not the same the code prints all records which are being compared. Also I have the same `C` and `C` properties of the objects but the program prints them anyway even though they are the same.

How can I print only the elements which are not same and only once? It basically prints every comparison that it makes.

I save everything into a set and I get rid of the duplicates but its not good solution. There should be a way to print only the object which has different `getC()`. Also my biggest problem is that it prints objects which have the same value for `C`.

**EDIT:** Object `a` and Object `d` are the same type of objects (say `Person`). The `getM()` is simple getter which returns the name of the object. `getB()` is simple getter which returns the phone number of the object. `equals` is not overriden. It is just used as you would normally use it.

This is the real code and real output of the program:

```
for (Apn a : aosp_mms_settings)
for (Apn d : db_mms_settings) {
    if (a.getMcc().equals(d.getMcc())
            && a.getMnc().equals(d.getMnc())) {

        if (!a.getApn().equals(d.getApn())) {

            String toPrint = "[MCC: " + a.getMcc() + " MNC: "
                    + a.getMnc() + " OTHER MCC" + d.getMcc()
                    + " OTHER MNC : " + d.getMnc() + "]"
                    + " < APN: " + a.getApn() + ">" + "Other APN:"
                    + d.getApn();

            System.out.println(toPrint);
            different_apns.add(toPrint);
        }

[MCC: 206 MNC: 20 OTHER MCC206 OTHER MNC : 20] < APN: mms.base.be>Other APN:mms.be
[MCC: 206 MNC: 20 OTHER MCC206 OTHER MNC : 20] < APN: mms.base.be>Other APN:mms.be
[MCC: 206 MNC: 20 OTHER MCC206 OTHER MNC : 20] < APN: mms.base.be>Other APN:mms.be
[MCC: 206 MNC: 20 OTHER MCC206 OTHER MNC : 20] < APN: mms.base.be>Other APN:mms.be
[MCC: 206 MNC: 20 OTHER MCC206 OTHER MNC : 20] < APN: mms.base.be>Other APN:mms.be
[MCC: 206 MNC: 20 OTHER MCC206 OTHER MNC : 20] < APN: mms.base.be>Other APN:mms.be
[MCC: 206 MNC: 20 OTHER MCC206 OTHER MNC : 20] < APN: mms.base.be>Other APN:mms.be
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more information. For instance, what does getM(), getC() and getB() return? Was equals() overridden for whatever these functions return?

Comment: It will add the toPrint object in case getM & getB is equal but getC is not eqal

Comment: please post complete syntax error free code, that helps more than anything.
point1: There is no print statement!
point2: `toPrint` double quote is missing!

Comment: Object don't have getM(), getC(), please check that if you properly override the equals method in the class M, class B and class C

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to see whether the two collections contain the same elements in the same order? Or the same elements, no matter their order? What exactly are the pairs you want to print?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the variable `different` is a *collection* too. In which case, you *may be* able to do this:

```
if (!different_apns.contains(toPrint) { //only print/add if it does NOT contain
    System.out.println(toPrint);
    different_apns.add(toPrint);
}
```